# How to sync the ubuntu repository

Tags: apt, repository

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal) version and it is at EOL.

The repositories for older releases that are not supported get moved to an archive server. These repositories are available at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com.

Now I have to set up this repository on my local server so that we can fetch packages from it instead of archive server. For setting repository I used **Apt-mirror** tool

And created the repository on the server.

Here is the mirror.list file

```
############# config ##################
#
 set base_path    /mirror/apt-mirror
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

############# Src path for 12.10 #############
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

After running `apt-mirror` command it creates following three folders

```
mirror  skel  var
```

I have created symlink for it in the /var/www folder using

```
sudo ln -s /mirror/apt-mirror/mirror/old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu  ubuntu
```

and it downloads about 60GB data.

Accordingly I have made changes in the "/etc/apt/source. list" file.

Here is the content of my sources.list file

```
deb http://XXXXXX.net/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://XXXXXX.net/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://XXXXXX.net/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

I test is using `sudo apt-get update`. But it is giving me following error

```
W: Failed to fetch http://XXXXXX.net/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

After debugging I found that I have missed **dists** directory in which some configuration is present (I really don't know what configuration is).

can any one know how to create this **dists** directory or is there any other way so that I can sync it my original repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can again start the `apt-mirror` process. It will continue from where it is stopped.